# Can't find the right selector for code lateron

Tags: html, css

I need to make a website for school. I try to use the [Checkbox Hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). It works in general, but i cant implement it in my website. Here is my problem: `input[type=checkbox]:checked > .menuitem` doesn't seem to effect the folowing:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
  <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><label for="toggle-1"><img src="images/menu.png" height="38" width="38"/></label></li>
     <li class="menuitem"><a href="About_us.html" target="_self">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I tried replacing my "> .menuitem" in `input[type=checkbox]:checked > .menuitem` with various things like `~` and `~ nav>ul>li` But i dont have any succes. Does anybody have an idea what i need to do?

i'm looking for a effect that does this:

```
If (checkbox is checked) {
     Hide a part of the webpage
}
```

On another note: I am not allowed to use anything else then HTML and CSS (So no Javascript or php etc.)

Comment: @sieltse can you provide your full code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + nav .menuitem
```

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + nav .menuitem{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
  <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><label for="toggle-1"><img src="images/menu.png" height="38" width="38"/></label></li>
     <li class="menuitem"><a href="About_us.html" target="_self">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: I tried your solution again, without changing any HTML or CSS. Still, i got a diffrend effect. I think that it didn't work becouse the old HTML/CSS was still in the memory. Anyway: It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The > css selector is immediate child selector, so browser search only for the first children of input tag - in this case nav element.

All you need is:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked .menuitem
```

Eventually you can add additional tags to be more specific

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked nav .menuitem
```

Or

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked nav ul li.menuitem
```